# Strange definition of spectrum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, topos-theory

The following is taken from [these notes](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/sdg.pdf).

**Definition 2.8.** Let $\mathscr E$ be some cartesian closed category and let $A$ be an $R$-algebra. The spectrum $\operatorname{Spec}_A(R[x_1,\dots ,x_n]/I)$ of a finitely presented $R$-algebra $R[x_1,\dots ,x_n]/I$ is a subobject ('subset', naively speaking) of $A^n$, which consists of elements in $A^n$ annihalating the polynomials of $I$.

**Examples:**

1. $\operatorname{Spec}_R(R[x])=R$
2. $\operatorname{Spec}_R(R[\epsilon])= \left\{ d\in R\mid d^2=0 \right\}$

What is the relationship of these definition to the usual definition as the set/space of prime ideals? Aren't the 'elements annihalating polynomials' precisely the elements of the vanishing locus of $I$? What's the connection between the spectrum (space of prime ideals) and the vanishing locus of an ideal of polynomials?

Comment: These are the $A$-points of $Spec (R [x_1, …, x_n]/I)$ in algebraic geometry.

Comment: @user40276 could you post a more detailed answer? I'm not very familiar with the nomenclature. I also edited the question.

Comment: I mean the morphisms $R [x_1, …, x_n] / I \rightarrow A$, this is exactly the same as finding $a_1, …, a_n \in A$ satisfying the relations on the ideal $I$. In other words, these are the solutions of the polynomial equations lying on $A$.

Comment: @user40276 I understand. If so, given an arrow $W_1\rightarrow W_2$, what is the induced arrow $R^{D(W_1)}\rightarrow R^{D(W_2)}$? I'm guessing there's an induced arrow $D(W_1)\rightarrow D(W_2)$, but the directions don't make sense because $D(W_1)=\mathsf{Hom}(W_1,R)$..

Comment: I don't understand your question. Spec is a contravariant functor.

Comment: I'm confused by formula $(60)$ under definition $2.10$ [here](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/sdg.pdf) - what is the right vertical arrow?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to your question. Anyway, the diagram is correct, Spec is contra variant and $R^{(-)}$ is contravariant too, this is why you've got a covariant thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qiaochu's answer is quite right. Since you are asking the question in the context of synthetic differential geometry, let me add an remark. The key to resolving your question "What is the relationship of these definition to the usual definition as the set/space of prime ideals?" is to realize that one can interpret the definition given in your question *internal to a given topos*. In this way the definition will describe a specific object of the topos. From the external point of view this object deserves the name "spectrum".

For instance, let $\mathcal{E}$ be the big Zariski topos of a scheme $S$, that is the category of sheaves on the Grothendieck site $\mathrm{Sch}/S$. This category contains the functor of points of any $S$-scheme (and also the "functor of points" of more general, not locally affine, objects). An $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ posseses an internal mirror image in this topos, an $\mathbb{A}^1_S$-algebra $\mathcal{A'}$. The spectrum of $\mathcal{A'}$ as defined in your question will then coincide with the functor of points of the relative spectrum of $\mathcal{A}$ (as ordinarily studied in algebraic geometry). Details are [in these notes](https://github.com/iblech/internal-methods/raw/master/notes.pdf), Section 13.1 ("Internal descriptions of basic constructions in relative scheme theory").

A similar statement can be made in the smooth setting. For instance, performing the construction given in your question internal to a suitable model of synthetic differential geometry based on $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-rings will yield the spectrum of an $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-ring from the external point of view.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this is just a confusing way of talking about morphisms $R[x_1, \dots x_n]/I \to R$ of $R$-algebras, or in algebraic geometry language the $R$-points of $\text{Spec } R[x_1, \dots x_n]/I$. In ordinary algebraic geometry these correspond to maximal (not prime) ideals if $R$ is an algebraically closed field by the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How do these abstract $R$-points give the concrete sets in the examples?

Comment: @Exterior: the polynomial algebra is the free commutative $R$-algebra on some generators, so maps from it to $R$ correspond to tuples of elements of $R$, namely the images of the polynomial generators. When you quotient by relations that imposes relations on these images accordingly.

Comment: @Exterior This just hold when $R$ is an algebraically closed field.